# Getting java.io.IOException: Error getting access token from metadata server at: http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/ Error

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am able to fetch the data from Bigquery using gcs-connector and spark-bigquery-in Spark application. But getting below error while trying to load data into Bigquery in GCP by using spark application.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error getting access token from metadata server at: http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token
```

Code:

```
df_bigquery.write.format("bigquery").option("credentialsFile", "D://input/absolute-vertex-321015-a78e81ae77a0.json").option("parentProject", "absolute-vertex-321015").option("temporaryGcsBucket","emp_demo_1").save("absolute-vertex-321015.org.employee_loaded")
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: same error, I want answers too, did you got the solution??

Comment: @alakmarShafin Can you share an error stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

May I help you with this?

This **Metadata endpoint**   `/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token` Returns the auth token that can be used to authenticate your application to other Google Cloud APIs.

As the error is: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: ***Error getting access token from metadata server*** at: http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token

**Use curl to request an access token and send a request to an API:**

1. On the instance where your application runs, query the metadata server for an access token by running the following command:

```
$ curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" \
-H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

The request returns a response similar to:

```
{
      "access_token":"ya29.AHES6ZRN3-HlhAPya30GnW_bHSb_QtAS08i85nHq39HE3C2LTrCARA",
      "expires_in":3599,
      "token_type":"Bearer"
 }
```

2. Copy the value of the `access_token` property from the response and use it to send requests to the API. For example, the following request prints a list of instances in your project from a certain zone:

```
$ curl https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/zones/[ZONE]/instances \
-H "Authorization":"Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]"
```

where:

`[PROJECT_ID]` is the project ID for this request.

`[ZONE]` is the zone to list instances from.

`[ACCESS_TOKEN]` is the access token value you got from step 1.

**Note:**

You can use the access token only for scopes that you specified when you created the instance. For example, if the instance has been granted only the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/storage-full scope for Cloud Storage, then it can't use the access token to make a request to BigQuery.

For information about the parameters that you can set in your request, see the parameters documentation.

[If you want to Authenticating applications with a client library](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#clientlib) use this reference.

I am happy to help, let me know if these steps resolve your issue.